# 10mb/s stucked on my new router

Tags: windows

Sooo. No port problem, no cable problem, no drivers problem. Buuut, my ethernet adaptor say i have 10 mb/s, and my laptop say i have 100mb/s(same cable). In past, i fix this problem activating and desactivating the adaptor, but when i changed the router, and try to do the same thing, it connect and disconnect a few times, and when stop do this, it stay stucked at 10mbs. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried a different cable?

Comment: One Ethernet NIC may be more tolerant to bad cables than another. What kind of NIC are you having problems with (onboard, USB, PCIe, …)? Virtually all Ethernet hardware can do gigabit speeds these days. What leads to you to expect 100 Mbit/s?

Comment: Note about "I tried everything. And when i say everything, i mean EVERYTHING". If you really believe this then you should assume we cannot help you, because there is nothing left to try. What's the point of asking then? But if you hope (and I'm sure you do) we will figure out something new then obviously it will be something you haven't tried. Thus stating you tried everything carries no useful information, it just introduces a drama factor additionally exaggerated by CAPITALS. We value being strict, not dramatic.

Comment: You will want to [edit] your question to provide hardware specifics, and some additional diagnostic information, other than “I have tried everything” because your question cannot be answered in its current state

Answer (score 1):

> I tried everything. ..... I mean EVERYTHING. I changed the router.

Get a new, high quality USB Ethernet Adapter with drivers for your laptop and use that.

Also see if there is a firmware update for your new router.

Double check the cable you use.

If you have done what I suggested (new network card and firmware) and still have the slow speed issue, then:

(1) check main computer hardware.

(2) if necessary, reinstall your operating system .

Also (given some comments in your other question) and if you upgraded the firmware in the new router, you may need to try yet another new, different brand, router and make sure your network card is compliant with the new, different brand, router.

Comment: i did this already ;(. You know, when i activet it, and after i deasactivate it, it s a few moments when it say something like ”connectin” or something idk, and if i double click it, it show me 100mbs, it stay a bit, after it s disconected. Do this 2-3 times, and at final it remain with 10mbs(this on new router). At old router, if i did what i said before, it stay at 100mbs.

Comment: Do you really mean on one machine: you used different network cards and different routers and you still get slow speed. If so reinstall your operating system and also check main computer hardware.